# enable annotations shiro spring

Tags: shiro

I followed [this subject](http://shiro.apache.org/spring.html) then created "working" code.

However, an unauthenticated person may call a method with annotations:

```
 @RequiresAuthentication
```

No exception is thrown.

(Important thing: I don't create a web application. It is a simple console program.)